# How do I split a Vec to return a tuple of the item at the given index and the rest of the vector?

Tags: rust

I want to iterate through a vector, and get a mutable reference to each item, and a mutable slice to the rest of the vector, so I can use both every iteration. Something like:

e.g:

```
for index in 0..model.len() {
    let (item, rest): (&mut Item, &mut [Item]) = model.split_rest_mut(index);
    item.do_something(rest);
}
```

e.g `[1,2,3,4,5,6].split_rest_mut(2)` would be `3, [1,2,4,5,6]`.

I would like this to be as performant as possible.

It seems to be similar behaviour to `split_at_mut`, so I imagine this should be possible.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: What with items in the middle? There are items before and after.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I want to capture all item in `rest` e,g `[1,2,3,4,5,6].split_rest_mut(2)` would be something like `(3, [1,2,4,5,6])` . I'll edit the question to clarify.

Comment: This is impossible, slices must be contiguous in memory. You need to allocate a separate `Vec`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the exact signature `split_rest_mut(usize) -> (&mut T, &[T])`, that is impossible: for an index which is neither for the first element nor the last element, the remaining elements are not contiguous in memory, and so cannot coexist in a single slice.

Instead, such a function would have to return two slices: one for the leading part of the slice and another one for the trailing part.

```
+-------------+-------------+--------------+
|  ...leading | middle item |  ...trailing |
+-------------+-------------+--------------+
```

Its implementation can be built with a combination of [`split_at_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at_mut) and [`split_first_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_first_mut).

```
pub fn split_at_rest_mut<T>(x: &mut [T], index: usize) -> (&mut T, &mut [T], &mut [T]) {
    assert!(index < x.len());
    // split in two
    let (leading, trailing) = x.split_at_mut(index);
    // split second half in [value, ...rest]
    let (val, trailing) = trailing.split_first_mut().unwrap();
    (val, leading, trailing)
}
```

Using:

```
let mut v = vec![1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 9];

assert_eq!(
    split_at_rest_mut(&mut v, 2),
    (&mut 5, &mut [1, 2][..], &mut [7, 8, 9][..]),
);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=dbe239f466ce23460a17c65a8a6af541)

Comment: This is very useful. Thank you.  Would it then be possible to concatenate the leading and trailing part into a single iterable? As you say, this result could not be a slice because the items will not be contiguous in memory, but if it could be some other none owning container, would that be possible?

Comment: @Blue7 Yes, it is possible. For instance, two iterators (`iter_mut`) can be [chained together](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.chain).

Answer (score 1):

It's not built in, but you can create it yourself easily enough based on `Vec::split_at_mut`:

```
fn split_rest_mut<T>(vec: &mut Vec<T>, mid: usize) -> (&mut T, &mut [T]) {
    let (left, right) = vec.split_at_mut(mid);
    (left.last_mut().expect("mid is 0"), right)
}
```

Usage:

```
    let (item, rest): (&mut Item, &mut [Item]) = split_rest_mut(&mut model, index);
```

`Vec::split_at_mut` is somewhat special because it returns *two* mutable references. Its implementation guarantees that those don't refer to the same values inside the vector, but [it takes unsafe code to implement it](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/slice/mod.rs.html#1684). So while you could theoretically create your own unsafe implementation of `split_rest_mut`, its safer to base it on `split_at_mut` instead.

Answer (score 0):

> How would I go about doing this?

Call `split_at_mut` and retrieve the last element of the first slice as your "current"?

Alternatively, use a [slice pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html#rest-patterns): https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=67d007bac2a94ff2cdcfbf36cdc4da35

```
if let [head, tail@..] = &mut model[i..] {
    *head += 1;
    println!("{}, {:?}", head, tail);
}
```

edit:

> e.g [1,2,3,4,5,6].split_rest_mut(2) would be 3, [1,2,4,5,6].

that's not possible. A slice is a contiguous buffer. You can have a "slice before", "focus", "slice after" using `split_at_mut` and `split_first_mut` or `split_last_mut`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=14cd90a694ffcb976f6e774a96d5d2c6

```rust
fn focus<T>(s: &mut [T], i: usize) -> Option<(&mut [T], &mut T, &mut [T])> {
    let (head, tail) = s.split_at_mut(i);
    let (focus, tail) = tail.split_first_mut()?;
    Some((head, focus, tail))
}
```

If you want a non-contiguous sequence you need to look at something like ndarray, and even then I'm not sure they'd have such an odd collection.